# Stream Output (SO) stage in Directx 12?

Tags: directx

Does Directx 12 have a Stream output Stage?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the documentation for setting the SO target can be [found here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dn986886(v=vs.85).aspx). The pipeline chart shows you stream output in the pipeline (over there on the right):

[image]

Going forward, for many features, you can typically assume nearly the same functionality as DX11.